# Owner of the Case should not be the Approver

Tags: trigger, approval-process

I have a scenario where a Case owner who is part of the Approval Queue is able to approve the Case. I want to prevent that from Happening and i am having tough time to Validate that.

It seems we cannot call Validation rule while someone is approving a record. So that is ruled out.

I started coding trigger for Case, where i try to capture the event of someone approving the Case but not able to get any pointers how to proceed.

Please help.

Thanks,
RK

Comment: Can you add the code that you have now?

Comment: Don't use a (that) queue as an approver?

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to access the Owner details (such as ID), Override the current approve button so that it checks for the current user's id and matches it against the owner's id.

I am not too sure how the approval queue works in your organization but if you provide more details, I could look at the code and guide you.